# Category listing page shows fatal error

Tags: magento-1.9, category-products

On clicking home page link to category page, the page shows the following error.

Fatal error: Call to a member function getId() on a non-object in xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx\app\code\core\Mage\Review\Block\Product\View\List.php on line 40

Can anyone help me to fix it?

Comment: have you changed any code recently ?

Comment: ya. Actually i have just integrated theme to customer login form. That's all

Answer (score 2):

I bet you are trying to list the reviews in the product list page.
in case I'm right, it doesn't work like you are doing it. You cannot use `Mage_Review_Block_Product_View_List` for showing reviews in the product list page.
That block needs to be in a "one single product context" (aka Product page) because it expects `Mage::registry('product')` to return a valid product model instance.

The solution in your case would be:

1. Remove the reviews from the product listing page
2. Use an other block that extends `Mage_Review_Block_Product_View_List` but with a different `getProductId` method. Something like this (untested):

   ```
   public function getProductId()
   {
       if ($this->getProduct()) {
            return $this->getProduct()->getId();
       }
       return parent::getProductId();
   }
   ```

now you can get the reviews in the list page like this:

```
<?php $reviewBlock = Mage::app()->getLayout()->createBlock('[module]/block_alias_here')->setProduct($_product);?>
<?php //do your magic with $reviewBlock?>
```

where `$_product` is the current iteration from the product list to be shown.